# How can a regex negative lookahead be made to work multiple times on the same line?

Tags: php, regex, pcre, regex-lookarounds

How can my regex be made to work across the same line?

It should match any instance of 'string' unless that is immediately followed by '<<'

Modifier: s

PCRE:

```
(?!.*?\<<)string
```

### Test String:

```
string<< string string

string string<< string 

string string string<< 

string string string
```

### Current result (matches in bold)

string<< **string string**

string string<< **string**

string string string<<

**string string string**

### Intended result

string<< **string string**

**string** string<< **string**

**string string** string<<

**string string string**

[Link to regex101](https://regex101.com/r/qP7rB7/2)

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By surrounding by *word boundary* like this.

`/\bstring\b(?!<<)/` This will look for `string` having word boundary on both side but not followed by `<<`

[Updated your regex.](https://regex101.com/r/qP7rB7/3)

Comment: Thank you. I tried applying that idea to a more complicated regex and unfortunately it only half worked, is there an anchor that will work for this?
https://regex101.com/r/lG8jV9/1

Comment: Are you trying to match URL or just a string followed by `<<` ?

Comment: Match a URL unless followed by << (or '.onion' as well)